# Merge multiple applications in same Solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have two completely independent applications (.sln), both `Asp.net Web Api`

`FilesManager.Web.Api` and `ImageUtilities.Web.Api`

We need to merge these two applications into only one solution, so we can deploy them together, as one application.

I still want to keep the applications in their own repositories (.sln), and the "wrapper" solution should only group them together somehow.

What is the fastest / efficient way of achieving this?

One solution i found is to create the wrapper Solution, and simply add the DLLs from the both applications.

Are there any other solutions of merging two `Web Api` applications together?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a blank 'wrapper' solution in a folder of choice
- Put the 'FilesManager.Web.Api' and 'ImageUtilities.Web.Api' project folders in a newly created folder
- Add the projects to the solution (rightclick solution => add existing project) => select corresponding csproj files
- Copy the original sln files to the newly created folder and edit them with notepad where needed (in case the references to the csproj files are incorrect)

Example:

[image: Tree representation of folder structure]